# Use "tf shelvesets" to get shelvesets sorted by creation time?

Tags: tfs, tfvc, tf-cli

Using `tf shelvesets`, I get a list of all the the shelvesets I've created.

The problem is, they are sorted *alphabetically*.

**Is there any way to use `tf` to get a list of shelvesets sorted by creation date?** I want to be able to easily see the (few) most recent shelvesets I've made, as I have accumulated quite a few now, and am usually (not always) only interesting in the recently created ones.

The version as reported by `tf`: Team Foundation Version Control Tool, Version 15.117.26727.0

**Edit:** If this isn't possible with `tf`, I am open to alternatives that I can run from a terminal.

Comment: Not sure if the terminal include visual studio or some other third party tool. Update the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

You should be able to simply type in your user name in the **Find Shelvesets** window and hit Enter in Visual Studio. The result is automatically sorted by creation time. The recently created ones display at the top of the list.

[image]

Another option is using some third-party tool such as [Team Foundation Sidekicks](http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/). There is a Shelveset Sidekick application , could easily filter the shelveset as you need.

[image]

---

It's not able to use `tf shelvesets` command to sort the shelveset.  And unlike a changeset, a shelveset is a non-versioned entity. You need to print all info and use regex  to search or some other tool to sort yourself.

```
tf shelvesets /format:detailed > log.txt
```

**Detailed** displays the shelveset name, owner, and comment in addition to a list of associated work items and any check-in notes.

There has also been a related user voice to better find/filter shelvesets and on backlog :

> **Shelveset search improvement**
>
> https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/2037731-shelveset-search-improvement

Comment: Yeah, I've used Visual Studio's "Find Shelvesets" in the past, I was hoping there would be a leaner solution that wouldn't require Visual Studio.  Team Foundation Sidekicks sounds promising, I'll have to give that a try.  Thanks!